# Run script on specific file type

Tags: search, applescript, subdirectory

I'm fairly new in the work of applescript and was wondering if someone can help me with this.

I'm currently writing script that will do a lot of things, one of them will be looking in a folder for files that have the .mhl extension to run a terminal command on them.  I've paste the part of my script bellow.  Now, this seems to work fine except fore one little detail.  the .mhl files need to be at the first level of my folder.  The problem is that my folder contains subfolder which contains the .mhl.  Is there a way I can tell this script to look in the entire folder (subfolder include)?

Thanks a lot

```
set input to "/Source"
tell application "System Events" to set theFiles to POSIX path of (files of folder input whose name contains ".mhl")
repeat with i in theFiles
    set filecount to 1
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script "mhl verify -f " & POSIX path of i & ""
    end tell
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably easier to use the find command but here is an AS approach...

```
set input to POSIX file "/Source"
tell application "Finder" to set theFiles to (files of entire contents of folder input whose name extension = "mhl") as alias list

tell application "Terminal"
    if not (exists window 1) then reopen
    activate
end tell

repeat with aFile in theFiles
    set filePath to aFile's POSIX path
    tell application "Terminal"
        do script "mhl verify -f " & quoted form of filePath in window 1
    end tell
end repeat
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I did try it and it's almost working.  For some reason, I don't know why, I had to change the ''whose name extension = "mho"'' to''whose name contain ".mhl"''  But once that done, it work perfectly :-)

Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. If I have answered your question, accept it by ticking the checkmark so other users know it is no longer open.

Comment: Will do :-)

but I have one more question.  Do you know of a way that I can get the path of my new folder as an input?  What I'm trying to achieve is this.

1- Copy a folder ''A'' to a new destination ''B''
2- Once the copy's complete, look for mhl files in the new subfolder ''A'' that was copy in the ''B'' destination. and run the mhl verification


Thanks again for your help

Comment: Oh, almost forgot.  The check for mhl really need to occur in the new copy folder (meaning that if there's already other folder in the destination, those should be ignore.